# « Auprès de », « Avec », « en présence de » ou « devant »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Il se moque de moi auprès de sa conjointe.

> Il se moque de moi avec sa conjointe.

> Il se moque de moi en présence de sa conjointe.

> Il se moque de moi devant sa conjointe.

——-

> Il lui arrive de me tourner en dérision devant sa conjointe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« **Auprès de** » est précis en cela qu'on sait qu'une seule personne se donne à la moquerie et que seule la conjointe est témoin ou sensée l'être, et que de plus elle en est la réceptrice voulue.

« **Avec** », qui est un peu une préposition à tout faire, est en comparaison, vague, puisqu'elle ne permet pas de savoir si la conjointe elle aussi  serait un auteur de la moquerie, ni de savoir si cela est fait en présence d'autres personnes.

« **En présence** » est plus précis qu'« avec » parce qu'on peut déduire que la conjointe n'est qu'une réceptrice passive ; ce n'est pas précis au point de  permettre d'inférer avec certitude que d'autres personnes sont présentes, bien que le plus souvent c'est ce que l'on tend à faire.

« **Devant** » est équivalent à « en présence ».

La dérision est, pourrait-on dire, une moquerie forte et qui repose sur ce qui est perçu, du moins par certains, comme des vérités objectives ; ce n'est donc pas un synonyme de moquerie, qui est un terme général couvrant même la taquinerie.

Answer (score 2):

Plutôt d'accord avec les constats faits dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50386/26366) mais ma perception est moins nuancée :

> Il se moque de moi auprès de sa conjointe.

Ça me fait penser à un type de phrase comme *porter plainte auprès de* et je trouve ça vieillot et un peu inusité avec *(se) moquer*.

---

> Il se moque de moi avec sa conjointe.

Je comprends *en compagnie de*, voire *ensemble*.

---

> Il se moque de moi en présence de sa conjointe.

Probablement ce que j'écrirais, à l'oral je le trouverais plus recherché que ce qui suit...

---

> Il se moque de moi devant sa conjointe.

Ce que [je](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/26366/s%C3%A91lance-lal%C3%A9a?tab=profile) trouve de plus usuel dans la vie de tous les jours pour dire que ça n'implique pas la participation de sa conjointe.